# How to avoid Authentication in Json Server or JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

This is my code copied on line for the JSON Server data

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const APP_SECRET = "myappsecret";
const USERNAME = "admin";
const PASSWORD = "secret";

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

  if ((req.url == "/api/login" || req.url == "/login")
    && req.method == "POST") {
    if (req.body != null && req.body.name == USERNAME
      && req.body.password == PASSWORD) {
      let token = jwt.sign({ data: USERNAME, expiresIn: "1h" }, APP_SECRET);
      res.json({ success: true, token: token });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: false });
    }
    res.end();
    return;
  } else if ((((req.url.startsWith("/api/products")
    || req.url.startsWith("/products"))
    || (req.url.startsWith("/api/categories")
      || req.url.startsWith("/categories"))) && req.method != "GET")
    || ((req.url.startsWith("/api/orders")
      || req.url.startsWith("/orders")) && req.method != "POST")) {
    let token = req.headers["authorization"];
    if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer<")) {
      token = token.substring(7, token.length - 1);
      try {
        jwt.verify(token, APP_SECRET);
        next();
        return;
      } catch (err) { }
    }
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```

But now in my application(Angular), I would like to use the data without authentication. I need to modify, delete the data.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: delete the login and token checking code and you are good to go

Comment: I changed like this inside of the { } /////  if (req.method == "POST" ) {
    if (req.body != null ) {
      res.json({ success: true });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: false });
    }
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  next();     but still not working well

Comment: update your answer with your new code so I can see what you are doing